# In Discord, is there a way to add some custom metadata in a Message/MessageEmbed?

Tags: discord, metadata, message

I have a bot which produces messages whith components. The actions binded to the components depend on data specific to the message, hence my problem.

The data could be resolved from the message content, but I'd like to avoid this operation (for reasons you can imagine). The simplest way would be to store everything in a sort of dictionary (message id => wanted data), but my app is stateless.

I could use a external database, but I don't want to go that far. I could use the customId property. It's quite dirty, but works for small data. I could use an other property, but which one ?

Any other solutions would be welcome...

Comment: What did you find out about this?